# Generating a 3D plot by revolution of a curve

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to revolve a 2D curve to generate a 3D surface plot.

I've tried using

```
[X,Z,Y] = cylinder(u);
surf(X,Y,Z), axis square
```

this, however, revolves my curve around the wrong axis. How do I go about changing the axis?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 4):

To rotate the axis of the cylinder, you can simply change the order of X, Y, and Z.

```
[X,Y,Z] = cylinder(u);

surf(X,Y,Z) %# rotation around Z
surf(Z,X,Y) %# rotation around X
surf(Y,Z,X) %# rotation around Y
```

**EDIT**

To change the axis of rotation of your curve, you have to calculate the surface. For example, to rotate `y = sin(alpha)` with `alpha = 0:0.1:pi` around the y-axis, you can write

```
r = 0:0.1:pi;
z = sin(r);
theta = 0:pi/20:2*pi;
xx = bsxfun(@times,r',cos(theta));
yy = bsxfun(@times,r',sin(theta));
zz = repmat(z',1,length(theta));
dfig,surf(xx,yy,zz)
axis equal
```

[image]

Comment: Nope, that only changes the orientation of the plot displayed!!

Comment: @Ngan Shan: Ok, I understand now. I've added another way to change the axis of rotation.

Comment: That's a brilliant way of rotating it Jonas. Thanks. The problem is, I've got more than one curve to rotate and the matrix multiplication fails when I use your method. It works just fine, I've edited the question with my code.

Comment: That's a brilliant way of rotating it Jonas. Thanks. The problem is, I've got more than one curve to rotate and the matrix multiplication fails when I use your method. It works just fine with one curve, I've edited the question with my code. Could you take a look at it and tell me how I could do the same for all the 2D plots.

Comment: @Ngan Shan: If you have multiple curves, then you have to create a surface for each one separately.