# 2D plot in 3D polar graph

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, surf, polar-coordinates

I would like to plot a 3D graph, y=100-x^2, cycle around the Y axis in 360 degrees. Eventually to become like a cone. Is that possible? I have an array `x=1:1:100`, and an array `y`, size(1 100).

I tried an Z array, `z=1:1:100` as the 3th axis in the base of the cone. With plot3 I done the one graph of y=100-x^2. I would like to kinda animate it and have eventually a cone, or a surface cone.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
r = 1:1:100;
y = 100-r.^2;
theta = 0:pi/20:2*pi;
xx = bsxfun(@times,r',cos(theta));
zz = bsxfun(@times,r',sin(theta));
yy = repmat(y',1,length(theta));
surf(xx,yy,zz)
```

Source: [Generating a 3D plot by revolution of a curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208447/generating-a-3d-plot-by-revolution-of-a-curve)

Comment: seems...yes . I need to rotate the y graph around y axis. As I have it now, the 2D graph is for positive and negative x. I need or to rotate this graph 180 degrees or to rotate tha half 360 degrees.

Comment: you can change the value of `theta` according to your problem statement.