# MATLAB 2D plot parabolic line rotation to form a cone in 3D

Tags: matlab, animation, 3d, plot, surf

I would like to make a cone surface plot using: the distance vector 'X=1:1:100' (size 1 100) and the data vector Y=1:1:100 (size 1 100). In 2D the plot is a kinda parabolic equation 'Y=100-X^2' ( y > 0 and -a < x < +a ).

I would like to rotate the line plot by 180 degrees, with step every 1 degree, around x=0(y axis), forming a cone in 3d space. Is it possible? Please, any idea is more than welcome.

Comment: Hi, do you want the surface of revolution (a cone is the surface of revolution of linear equations like y = x) of the equation y = 100 - X^2? And do you want to make this into an animated plot?

Comment: my equation is like a cone mountain, close to the parabolic y=100-x^2. It is calculated inside my script, forming an array on every time step. I need for every time step, having the Y array of data, to form a 3D cone, rotating the line around y axis. Eventually I need a surface for every step, so will be an animation for 100 time steps. More or less, these cone will be increased in volume after 100 steps. I have done that in 2D, as a parabolic line which increasing in y and x axis. I need to be in 3D, cause as I said this is like a material which blow up in 3D.

Comment: possible duplicate of [2D plot in 3D polar graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030074/2d-plot-in-3d-polar-graph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 3D polar plot from the Mathworks website is probably what you're looking for:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13200-3d-polar-plot

It looks like a pretty sweet function. Note the 'Angular Range' property described.

But you can also get what you want without it:

```
figure(); hold on;
for theta = linspace(0, pi, 100) % Not exactly sure how you want to vary theta
    [T, R] = meshgrid(linspace(0, theta, 100), 1:100);
    [X, Y] = pol2cart(T,R); 
    Z = 100 - R.^2; % Compute the surface of revolution
    surf(X,Y,Z); % Plot the surface
    pause(1); % Wait one second
end
```

Let me know if this isn't what you're describing, or if you need more help.

Comment: thank you, but it is not working to me...
Yes, I want the surface of evolution of my graph, rotated arround y axis (x=0).

Comment: Could you explain what isn't working? What's the difference between what this produces and what you would like?

Comment: on your code, I just see a black line which has nothing to do with my data.

Comment: I can send  you a link of my export graph and you will understand exactly what I want. Can I do that here?

Comment: Sure. It would be best if you could embed the graph in your question, though.

Comment: I add a drobox link. As you can see every time step until the maximum step I have these cone lines. I would like to rotate 360 degrees each one, at least for the last one.

Comment: The pic will be the point that will define the rotation axis. I have done that. I just need lets say 360 of these plots in 3D, eventually to be a surface.

Comment: Does the following code produce a surface for you:
figure(); %hold on;
theta = 2*pi;
[T, R] = meshgrid(linspace(0, theta, 100), 1:100);
[X, Y] = pol2cart(T,R); 
Z = 100 - R.^2; % Compute the surface of revolution
surf(X,Y,Z); 

?
It should provide a surface like you've described, not a black line.

Comment: I change that... make a surface... but is not logical one... what is the 100 ? the maximum number of gridpoints?

Comment: It is still running... seems that it is working, but still I am not sure if teh curve is the right one. the XYZ axis have different numbers... I will let you know when it will stop

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48434/discussion-between-mattg-and-user1640255)

Comment: I need to change the Z, as Z is an array that calculated inside the script.