# Generating cylindery symmetric 3D data by revolution of a 2d plane around one axis

Tags: matlab, 3d, interpolation

Following a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208447/generating-a-3d-plot-by-revolution-of-a-curve?rq=1) that was asked,  I wanted to create a 3d volume, i,e, `f(x,y,z)`, starting from a 2D matrix `I(x,y)` and not just a curve.

For example, assume `I=peaks(10)`, how can I revolve it around one of the axes (say the y-axis), to get a 3D matrix? Will it be easier if I instead have `I(r,theta)`?
 I can rotate a plane in 3D, but this will not be part of a 3D matrix, just new x,y,z coordinates.

Comment: What do you intend to do with this data afterwards? Perhaps you don't even need to revolve it, but rather construct a "projection function" that takes 3 parameters (e.g. `x,y,z`) and maps them to the surface you know?

Comment: show it in 3d form, using alpha map or isosurfaces, somthing like that http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17260/3d-heatmap-density-plot...

Comment: The problem is that your 3D space is discrete. Assuming the plane to rotate is in ZX, and you revolve around Z, then you need, for every X,Y, a rotation of the original plane. Some x,y conbinations can be reused, such as 45deg, but for the rest you need an specific rotation of the plane for that XY value. Should be easy, but long. If you still have problems I may try to get an answer written later.

Comment: that's more or less what I had in mind, but doing this 3d histogram correctly is the challenge. Maybe another way to go is using concentric sphere's and plotting the data on the sphere surfaces...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's pretty straightforward to check the indices of your expected 3d array, find geometrically which `I(x,y)` value they correspond to (yes, essentially with a Cartesian to cylindrical transformation), then filling up each value as necessary.

Here's a minimal version of what I mean. It is assumed that the input array of size `[N,N]` corresponds to coordinates `x`, `y` in `0:N-1`. The input array is assumed to be oriented along the `xz` plane, and it is rotated about the `z` axis in order to generate the output array `V`. The dimensions of `V` thus correspond to `-(N-1):N-1` along `x` and `y`, and `0:N-1` along `z`. Thus the dimensions of `V` are `[2*N-1, 2*N-1, N]`.

Demonstrating two approaches (using `griddata` and `interp2`, respectively), complete with plotting for reproducibility:

```
% size of the problem
N = 10;

% input data
I = peaks(N);

% two sets of output V for two methods
V1 = zeros(2*N-1,2*N-1,N);
V2 = zeros(2*N-1,2*N-1,N);    
[i1,i2,i3] = ndgrid(1:2*N-1,1:2*N-1,1:N);
% [i1(:), i2(:), i3(:)] are the contiguous indices of V
% z dimension is the same as of I: rotate around z axis

% it will be assumed that input 1:N span elements from 0 to N-1
% output V spans -(N-1):N-1 along x and y
x = i1-N; % -(N-1):N-1
y = i2-N; % -(N-1):N-1
z = i3-1; %      0:N-1
% input array I is in xz plane, rotated along z axis, geometrically speaking

% identify the cylindrical coordinates of each voxel [i1,i2,i3]
[~,r_out,z_out] = cart2pol(x,y,z); % theta is redundant; z_out===z

% identify the coordinates of each input pixel with the above
[j1,j2] = meshgrid(1:N,1:N);
r_in = j1-1; % Cartesian input x <-> cylindrical output r
z_in = j2-1; % Cartesian input y <-> cylindrical output z
% note that j1 and j2 are swapped with respect to x and y
% but this is what interp2 will expect later

% interpolate each voxel based on r and z
method = 'nearest'; %probably the least biased
%method = 'cubic'; %probably the prettiest

V1(:) = griddata(r_in,z_in,I,...
        r_out(:),z_out(:),method);

V2(:) = interp2(r_in,z_in,I,...
        r_out(:),z_out(:),method,...
        0); % extrapolation value, otherwise NaNs appear outside


% plot two slices: xz plane and general rotated one
figure;
% generate rotated versions of the xz plane by rotating with phi around z
for phi=[0, -25, -90]/180*pi
    [xp0,zp] = meshgrid(-(N-1):0.1:N-1,0:0.1:N-1);
    xp = xp0*cos(phi);
    yp = xp0*sin(phi);

    subplot(121);
    slice(y,x,z,V1,xp,yp,zp);
    title('griddata nearest');
    shading flat;
    axis equal vis3d;
    hold on;

    subplot(122);
    slice(y,x,z,V2,xp,yp,zp);
    title('interp2 nearest, extrap 0');
    shading flat;
    axis equal vis3d;
    hold on;
end
```

[image: result]

As you can see, `slice` directly plots the data in `V`, so this is an accurate representation of the resulting 3d array.

For reference, here is a single specimen of the input `I = peaks(10)`:

[image: input shape]